Dropdown Rebuild Issue When Location Updates in Flutter
I’m working on a Flutter app where I have a dropdown widget that displays location data. The dropdown value is fetched asynchronously using a FutureBuilder. However, I’m facing two issues:
Dropdown Rebuild When Location Updates:
Whenever I update the locationData using setState(), the entire widget tree (including the FutureBuilder) rebuilds, which triggers a new call to getGeoData().
How can I prevent the dropdown from rebuilding when the location updates?
Dropdown Rebuild When Selecting an Item:
When I select an item from the dropdown, it also triggers a rebuild of the entire widget tree.
How can I avoid this behaviour and ensure that only the dropdown triggers futurebuilder rebuilds when an item is selected?
  const AuthQr({super.key});
  @override
  State<AuthQr> createState() => _AuthQrState();
}

class _AuthQrState extends State<AuthQr> {


//get data for future builder
  Future<GeoModel.GeoDataModel> getGeoData() async {
    return QrDataRepo().getGeoData(await Sf.getStringValuesSF(USER_ID));
  }


  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }



  GeoModel.Result? dropdownvalue;
  bool geofenceStatusFlag = false;
  Location? locationData;
  String error = "",
      messagedDigets = "Please Wait We Are Getting Data For You.";


//location updates callback, trigger from another child widget, removing setstate fixes //futurebuilder creationn issue

  Future<void> _onLocationChanged(Location location) async {
   //setState(() {
      locationData = location;
      logd("location data from qr $location");
   //});
  }


  Future<void> _onGeofenceStatusChanged(
      Geofence geofence,
      GeofenceRadius geofenceRadius,
      GeofenceStatus geofenceStatus,
      Location location) async {
    setState(() {
      logd('geoFence ${geofence.status}');
      switch (geofence.status) {
        case GeofenceStatus.ENTER:
          geofenceStatusFlag = true;
          messagedDigets = 'Please Scan QR';
          break;
        case GeofenceStatus.EXIT:
          geofenceStatusFlag = false;
          messagedDigets = 'Seems Like Your Left Office';
          break;
        case GeofenceStatus.DWELL:
          geofenceStatusFlag = true;
          messagedDigets = 'Please Scan QR';
          break;
        default:
          {
            geofenceStatusFlag = false;
            messagedDigets =
                'Seems Like Your Are Not In Office,Please Ensure, You Are Near Your Designated System';
          }
      }
      // geofenceStatus = geofence.status;
    });
  }
  _onError(dynamic error) {
    final errorCode = getErrorCodesFromError(error);

    if (errorCode == null) {
      /*   setState(() {
        geofenceStatusFlag = true;
      }); */
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        logd('Undefined error: $errorCode');
        this.error = errorCode.name;
        geofenceStatusFlag = false;
        messagedDigets = errorCode.name;
        /*       WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          //Not Working TODO: tony
          /*    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              this.error,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          )); */
        }); */
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 164, 203, 207),
                title: const Text(
                  'Authentication',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                  selectionColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 164, 203, 207),
                )),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 164, 203, 207),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/comps.png',
                          width: 200,
                          height: 200,
                        ),
                      ),
//this is the issue here 
                      FutureBuilder(
                        future: getGeoData(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          //dropdownvalue = snapshot.data?.result?.first;
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return const Text("Some Error Happened");
                          } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                          } else {
                            dropdownvalue = snapshot.data?.result?.first;
                            return DropdownButton(
                                elevation: 8,
                                value: dropdownvalue,
                                items: snapshot.data?.result?.map((item) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                      value: item, child: Text(item.lgd!));
                                }).toList(),
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                onChanged: (GeoModel.Result? newValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                                  });
                                });
                          }
                        },
                      ),

//my hunch was dropdownvalue creating this issue but it wasn't the case .
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: GeoFenceWidget(
                          latitude: double.parse(dropdownvalue?.lat ?? "0.0"),
                          longitude: double.parse(dropdownvalue?.long ?? "0.0"),
                          radius:
                              double.parse(dropdownvalue?.radiusInMtr ?? "0.0"),
                          onGeofenceStatusChanged: _onGeofenceStatusChanged,
                          onLocationChanged: _onLocationChanged,
                          onError: _onError,
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*       ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            appsList().then((value) {
                              for (var app in value) {
                                print(
                                    "${app.packageName} \t ${app.installedTimestamp}");
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text('Start barcode scan')), */

                      Text(messagedDigets,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 10, 150))),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            !geofenceStatusFlag
                                ? ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    SnackBar(
                                        content:
                                            Text("Please Wait then Try Again")))
                                : scanQR();
                          },
                          child: Text('Start QR scan')),

                      /*   Text('Scan result : $_scanBarcode\n',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)), */
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => sendQrData().then((value) =>
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(
                                      content: Text(
                                          value.statusMessage.toString())))),
                          child: Text('Send QR Data')),
                      /*    Expanded(
                        child: ListView(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text('Microsoft Edge (MacOs)'),
                              subtitle: Text('Last active today at 1:52 PM'),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text('Microsoft Edge (Windows)'),
                              subtitle: Text('Last active April 9, at 6.55 PM'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        /*  LayoutBuilder(builder:
                            (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                          return FutureBuilder(
                            future: appsList(),
                            builder: (buildContext, asyncSnapshot) {
                              if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                                print(asyncSnapshot.data.toString());
                                return ListView.separated(
                                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                        const Divider(),
                                    itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data!.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var dt =
                                          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                              asyncSnapshot.data?[index]
                                                      .installedTimestamp ??
                                                  0);
                
                                      // Format the DateTime object
                                      var formattedDate =
                                          '${dt.year}-${dt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
                                      return ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                              asyncSnapshot.data?[index].name ??
                                                  ""),
                                          subtitle:
                                              Text(formattedDate.toString()));
                                    });
                              } else if (asyncSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              } else {
                                print("error gtgtgt");
                                return Text(asyncSnapshot.data.toString());
                              }
                            },
                
  
                    ]),
              );
            })));
  }
}```

